# android give an error in create mediaplayer?

Tags: android, mobile

error :
Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
Unable to to create media player

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        try {

            MediaPlayer objMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            objMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            objMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://192.168.1.3:3000/songs/WakaWaka.mp3");
            objMediaPlayer.prepare();
            objMediaPlayer.start();


        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding mp.prepare(); before mp.start();

Comment: yes i try with that but still not working and also remove mp.start() then also gives an same error.

Comment: Did u try any other url source?

Comment: yes i try with other url source

Answer (score 2):

Check the Android Media Player [State Diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif).

You have to call reset() e prepare() before calling start().

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

private MediaPlayer objMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

objMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

```
       try {
        objMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);


        objMediaPlayer.prepare();

        objMediaPlayer.start();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help some people.. in order to stream a video from online, you must
add to 'AndroidManifest.xml'

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

i went thru your problem. But couldn't get much of it. One thing for sure is, the url what you have specified here doesn't exist. So I made use of my own and did a sample. Check it out,

```
 mediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
        try {


    mp.setDataSource("http://182.71.230.252/developers/blind_willie.mp3");
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mp.start();
```

Comment: not working with my code any change need to done in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: no. no permission was required. r u sure u r connected to net?